# Is frequentist statistics concerned with expectation?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Frequentist statistics sees probability as the expectation of the value. Expectation is the long-term average.

**Do Frequentists interpret probability as the expected value for that parameter?**

EDIT:

From what I understand, Frequentists interpret probability as the long-run average of this value. Well, isn't that what the expectation is? Okay - frequentists interpret probability as the expectation for that value.

QED right?

Comment: Probability is calculated for an event, and expected value is determined of a random variable.So I am not sure what your question is asking. Can you expand on the sentences using some equations that you might be referring to?

Comment: Sorry but it is still unclear what do you mean. "Probability", "parameter", and "expected value" have very precise meaning in statistics (check e.g. their Wikipedia entries) and you seem to mix them in some strange fashion. Probability of observing something is not the same as *the thing* itself. Probability is ***not*** the "average of the value". The average American mens height is 177 cm -- "177 cm" has nothing to do with probability! $\Pr(X=x) \neq x$!

Comment: Frequentists interpret probability as a long-run average is what I meant.

Comment: May be you mean **expected rescaled frequency** of that value?

Comment: The expected value of a Bernoulli variable $X \sim B(p)$ is indeed $p$. I can't think of a situation where it would be impossible to associate a Bernoulli variable with a given probability. 
This is exactly what is told in Wikipedia about frequentism: *Frequentist probability or frequentism is a standard interpretation of probability; it defines an event's probability as the limit of its relative frequency in a large number of trials.*

Comment: In this interpretation, it seems natural to define the expected value of a random variable as the limit of the arithmetic mean on a large number of random experiments.

Comment: Is then the law of large numbers a tautology? I don’t think so. This means that the law of large number *must* be true for a sound theory of probabilities. But you still have to construct a mathematical theory, in which probabilities and expected values are defined without reference to "a large number of experiments". When you prove the law of large numbers in this theory, you are verifying that this formalized theory captures well your a priori idea of probability and expected value.

Comment: @Elvis Bernoulli distribution is exception rather than a rule, because by definition it is parametrized by probability of success. In other cases probabilities and expected values are tied-up together but are *not* the same.

Comment: Of course expected value are not probabilities. But the frequentist interpretation of probability is just that a probability is the limit of frequencies in larger and larger number of trials, ie the limit of arithmetic means of Bernoulli variable, ie an expected value.

Comment: If this can reassure you, this is not mathematics, rather epistemology...

Answer (score 7):

Let $X$ be a random variable with density $f$, and let $A$ be an event that $X$ takes a value in a certain set $W$.

$$A = X \in W. $$

The probability of the event $A$ is $P(A)$. However, this can be rewritten as,

\begin{align*}
P(A) & = P(X \in W)\\
& = \int_{X \in W} f(x) dx\\
& = \int I(X \in W) f(x) dx\\
& = E\left[I(X \in W)  \right]\\
& = E\left[I(A)  \right]
\end{align*}

So the probability of observing a certain event A can be written as the long-run average. However, this has nothing really to do with frequentist statistics. This is just a property of probability.

EDIT

The differentiation I am trying to make here is that probability addresses an *event* and expectation addresses a random variable. The occurrence of an event is a random variable. For example, $A$ is the event, $I(A)$ is the random variable that indicates whether $A$ occurred or not. Thus, the chance of $A$ occurring can be rewritten as the expected value of the random variable $I(A)$.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. A frequentist says a scalar probability value is the long-term frequency of this value. Well, that is just another way of saying the expecation!

Comment: Yes, probability and expected value are exchangeable, using the argument I stated. However, the object on which probability and expectation are applied changes. Probability refers to an *event* and expectation refers to a *random variable*. And like I mentioned above, there is nothing inherently frequentist about it. Bayesians would also agree with the equation I have written down. Hint: not everything in statistics can be broken into Bayesian vs. frequentist.

Answer (score 3):

> From what I understand, Frequentists interpret probability as the
>   long-run average of this value. Well, isn't that what the expectation
>   is? Okay - frequentists interpret probability as the expectation for
>   that value.

No. If $\Pr(X=x_i) = p_i$, then [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of $X$ is

$$ E[X] = x_1 p_1 + \dots + x_n p_n $$

As you can see, expected value is defined in terms of **random variable** $X$, not of some value $x_i$. If you were interested in "probability of the random variable itself", then it does not have much meaning since it leads to

$$ \Pr \left(\bigcup_i x_i \right) = \Pr(\Omega) = \sum_i \Pr\left( x_i \right) = 1$$

by Kolmogorov's [axioms of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms). As you can see, this has nothing to do with expectation. Moreover, probabilities need to be bounded in $[0, 1]$, while random variables can have *any* values (e.g. for normal distribution $x \in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: It takes a a heavy abuse of notation to consider "$\sum_i x_i$" to be an event! (Especially considering the $x_i$ are numbers.) This makes the second equation difficult to interpret.  Is there perhaps a typographical error there?  Maybe you meant to write something like $$\sum_i \Pr(x_i)=1=\Pr(\Omega)=\Pr\left(\bigcup_i\{x_i\}\right)$$ instead? Even then, it's unclear what you mean by "probability of random variable itself."

Comment: @whuber I agree, that "probability of random variable itself" does not make any sense, but as for me this is *exactly* the problem in OP's reasoning that needs pointing out. As about notation -- you are right, I'll fix it.